# Как сделать файл исполняемым, подобно тому, как это делается на линукс?

Tags: android

У меня есть файл, который мне требуется сделать исполняемым. Я пытался это сделать как через термукс, так и через ES проводник. Термукс говорит, что я не рутирован, а в ES проводнике просто отсутсвует кнопка(или я не знаю где она), чтобы сделать файл исполняемым. Можно ли все таки сделать это как-то через ес проводник? Очень не хочется рутировать мобилу. У меня есть "догадки", что просто в термуксе у меня отсуствует рут, а так он и есть в ес проводнике.
Заранее не ругайте за какой-то бред, написанный мной, не сильно шарю в этом.

Что я имел в виду под исполняемостью:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас есть доступ на изменение файла? Файл лежит на файловой системе, которая позволяет сделать файл исполняемым?

Comment: @andreymal файл лежит на линукс, там я могу его менять, то есть ставить исполняемость или нет. Когда я его переместил на андроид и попытался через командную строку в термкус его открыть, то мне указало, что этот файл не исполняемый и его нужно установить через pkg install. Если же я пытаюсь установить через chmod права на его исполняемость, то мне выдает ошибку, что я не рутирован(но рут ставить на мобилу мне не хочется).
Когда я захожу в файловую систему андроид через ES проводник и хочу попробовать установить файл на его исполняемость, просто не вижу такого пункта в свойствах файла.

Comment: @andreymal сделать это через usb я не могу тоже, так как пк не видит мою мобилу

Comment: @andreymal ладно, я все таки рутировал мобилу, но теперь другая проблема:

Пытаюсь выдать разрешение на исполнение файла на андроид, но выдает ошибку. Пробовал также на эмуляторе genymotion — все работало. Мобилу свою рутировал, так что по сути все должно работать наверное. 
https://pastebin.com/syiuy5pS

Comment: На sdcard делать файлы исполняемыми невозможно, даже с рутом